# Exclude function definitions when dumping a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, dump

I have a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS functions loaded into it. I would like to dump out the schema of the database, but `pg_dump -s` dumps out the functions along with the table definitions.

Is there a way to exclude the functions and just dump the table definitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all I know, [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) do not support any such restriction.

You *could* move all your functions to a dedicated schema which you could exclude from the dump like this:

```
pg_dump mydb -N function_schema > mydump.sql
```

If you go that route, you can [migrate functions to another schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html) like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION myfunc() SET SCHEMA function_schema;
```

In this case I would also adapt the `search_path` in `postgresql.conf` (and possibly in the defaults for databases and roles)

```
SET search_path = public,function_schema [,more schemas]
```

As an **alternative**, you could leave the functions in their default schema `public` and not use that schema for anything else. Put your objects in one or more separate schemas. That should make upgrading PostGis easier.

It may be a good idea to *not* use the `public` schema for your objects. I usually reserve it for PostGis or other extensions that install into `public` by default. I like to use a dedicated schema for every application. Makes maintenance easier - including backups and granting permissions.

Comment: Or, you can use pg_restore's --list related options and manually trim the items from the list generated.

Comment: If you are coming here having problems with duplicate functions after restoring an old dump of a PostGIS DB you could investigate the upgrading choices of PostGIS https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#upgrading.