# Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, roles, privileges, sql-grant

Using PostgreSQL 9.0, I have a group role called "staff" and would like to grant all (or certain) privileges to this role on tables in a  particular schema. None of the following work

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA foo TO staff;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO staff;
```

Members of "staff" are still unable to SELECT or UPDATE on the individual tables in the schema "foo" or (in the case of the second command) to any table in the database *unless* I grant all on that specific table.

What can I do make my and my users' lives easier?

**Update:** Figured it out with the help of [a similar question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/60508/grant-select-to-all-tables-in-postgresql).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA foo TO staff;
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You found the shorthand to set privileges for all *existing* tables in the given schema. [The manual clarifies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS):

> (but note that `ALL TABLES` is considered to include **views** and **foreign tables**).

Bold emphasis mine. **`serial`** columns are implemented with `nextval()` on a sequence as column default and, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS):

> For sequences, this privilege allows the use of the `currval` and `nextval` functions.

So if there are `serial` columns, you'll also want to grant **`USAGE`** (or `ALL PRIVILEGES`) on **sequences**

```
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA foo TO mygrp;
```

Note: [`IDENTITY` columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) in Postgres 10 or later use implicit sequences that don't require additional privileges. (Consider upgrading `serial` columns.)

#### What about *new* objects?

You'll also be interested in [**`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`** for users or schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html#SQL-ALTERDEFAULTPRIVILEGES-NOTES):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA foo GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO staff;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA foo GRANT USAGE          ON SEQUENCES TO staff;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA foo REVOKE ...;
```

This sets privileges for objects created in the future automatically - but not for pre-existing objects.

Default privileges are *only* applied to objects created by the targeted user (`FOR ROLE my_creating_role`). If that clause is omitted, it defaults to the current user executing `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`. To be explicit:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE my_creating_role IN SCHEMA foo GRANT ...;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE my_creating_role IN SCHEMA foo REVOKE ...;
```

Note also that all versions of pgAdmin III have a subtle bug and *display* default privileges in the SQL pane, even if they do not apply to the current role. Be sure to adjust the `FOR ROLE` clause manually when copying the SQL script.

Comment: just so you know Erwin, 10 mins after you posted your advice, I needed it. Its like you knew what I was going to do... create a new table and find it didn't have the right privs. Your answer came to the rescue.

Comment: @punkish: I demand my precog badge! [Damn, that's already used for something else.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive)

Comment: When running `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA foo GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO staff;` how does it know what database? `SCHEMA foo` can exist in different database?

Comment: @J86: applies to the *current* database only - where the command is executed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Can I grant access for future tables/sequences to the **app_user** (read-write) provided that tables will be created by another dedicated **migration_user** automatically (flyway migrations are run at the app startup)?

Answer (score 57):

My answer is similar to [this one on ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/284278/142214).

## To Be Conservative

If you want to be more conservative than granting "all privileges", you might want to try something more like these.

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO some_user_;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO some_user_;
```

The use of `public` there refers to the name of the default schema created for every new database/catalog. Replace with your own name if you created a schema.

## Access to the Schema

To access a schema at all, for any action, the user must be granted "usage" rights. Before a user can select, insert, update, or delete, a user must first be granted "usage" to a schema.

You will not notice this requirement when first using Postgres. By default every database has a first schema named `public`. And every user by default has been automatically been granted "usage" rights to that particular schema. When adding additional schema, then you must explicitly grant usage rights.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA some_schema_ TO some_user_ ;
```

Excerpt from the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html):

> For schemas, allows access to objects contained in the specified schema (assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also met). Essentially this allows the grantee to "look up" objects within the schema. Without this permission, it is still possible to see the object names, e.g. by querying the system tables. Also, after revoking this permission, existing backends might have statements that have previously performed this lookup, so this is not a completely secure way to prevent object access.

For more discussion see the Question, [What GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17338621/642706). Pay special attention to [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355059/642706) by Postgres expert [Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer).

## Existing Objects Versus Future

These commands only affect existing objects. Tables and such you create in the future get default privileges until you re-execute those lines above. See the [other answer by Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353730/642706) to change the defaults thereby affecting future objects.

Comment: in addition to the two grants above, need one more grant:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO some_user_;

Comment: @NingLiu Thanks so much for pointing out GRANT USAGE, and for teaching me that. I added a section to the Answer.

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA is what I was looking for.