# How to grant all privileges on views to arbitrary user

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-grant, pgadmin

How do you grant read/select access on all functions and views to an arbitrary user?

I use `psql --user=postgres -d mydb -f myview.sql` to create several functions and views, and then I run:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
```

Having been granted all privileges, I would expect `myuser` to now have access to the functions and views created by the `postgres` user. However, when I try and access them with `myuser`, I get a "permission denied for relation..." error. Why is this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason is that you need additional privileges to access a view or table. Privileges on the database do not cover access to all objects in it.

It is different with functions: `EXECUTE` privilege is granted to `public` by default. **But** the function is executed with the privileges of the current user. You may be interested in the `SECURITY DEFINER` modifier for [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html). But normally it is enough to grant `SELECT` on involved tables.

[Per documentation about default privileges:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html)

> Depending on the type of object, the initial default privileges might
>   include granting some privileges to `PUBLIC`. The default is no public
>   access for tables, columns, schemas, and tablespaces; `CONNECT`
>   privilege and `TEMP` table creation privilege for databases; `EXECUTE`
>   privilege for functions; and `USAGE` privilege for languages.

You may be interested in this DDL command (requires Postgres **9.0** or later):

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

While connected to the database in question, of course (see [@marcel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275?noredirect=1#comment42690407_10491275) below), and as a user with sufficient privileges. You may also be interested in the setting `DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`:

- [Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730)

More detailed answer how to manage privileges:

- **[How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)**

[pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) has a feature for more sophisticated bulk operations:

[image]

Or you can query the system catalogs to create DDL statements for bulk granting / revoking ...

Comment: It took me an hour to realize that 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;' only makes sense when this command is executed when the user that is granting is *CONNECTED* to that database. If not, it just doesn't do anything (or at least it doesn't give the select permission to the user). In the shell of the superuser use \c databasename.

Comment: This doesn't grant the user permission to sequences.

Comment: @Cerin: The question asks for *views*, you don't need privileges on sequences for that (at least not at the time of writing where updatable views were not yet implemented). For more privileges see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918367/grant-privileges-for-a-particular-database-in-postgresql/24923877#24923877