# Restore database with changed privileges

Tags: postgresql, privileges, sql-grant, postgresql-9.0, pg-restore

We have two PostgreSQL servers. On web server1 `pguser1` is the associated user who creates all database objects required to work with the web application. Let's say, all objects are in `schema1`.
Similarly, on server2 `pguser2` creates data for Web server 2.

I have taken a schema backup (custom option in the backup window from pgadmin) from server1. When I restore to server2 I want all privileges and ownership of objects to be with `pguser2` and nothing with `pguser1`.

How can this be achieved? If possible, an option during during restore (pg_restore command) would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It would very much simplify your task if you `GRANT` privileges and ownership to a non-login role (a.k.a. group). Let's name it `foo_admin`. On server1 you

```
GRANT foo_admin TO pguser1;
```

On server2 you

```
REVOKE foo_admin FROM pguser1;
GRANT foo_admin TO pguser2;
```

All done. Or better yet: hack the dump file and replace `1` with `2` in the line

```
GRANT foo_admin TO pguser1;
```

.. before you restore. `pguser2` has to be created first, of course.

Now, just make sure, when you create anything on server1 to

```
ALTER TABLE wuchtel12.game OWNER TO foo_admin;
```

And set privileges. You can preset privileges per schema. Something like:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES
TO foo_admin;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema1
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, USAGE ON SEQUENCES
TO foo_admin;
```

This works identically on server1 and server2.
[More details and links in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730).

---

You might also be interested in the Grant Wizard of pgAdmin. Details in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275#10491275)