# Postgres user permission is not working

Tags: postgresql

I have created a Postgres user `user1`, and granted all permission to `my_db`, when I try to select a table from the database, I'm getting a permission denied error.

Create user1

```
>>zya$ psql -d postgres
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# CREATE USER user1  WITH PASSWORD 'password1';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db to user1;
GRANT
postgres=# \q
```

Login as user1

```
>>zya$ psql -d my_db --username=user1
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

    my_db=> SELECT DISTINCT  name FROM user_tbl order by id;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation user_tbl
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give all the permissions to a user on a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/give-all-the-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-db)

Comment: It's a duplicate, and the solutions in that question will work for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;
```

you have to change database `my_db` owner to your username `user1`

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late but what you might want to do is to assign 
This is from my trials and I was able to fix similar issue. It seems you have to set similar privileges to tables function and sequences like shown below

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE yourdb TO yourusr;
    GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA your_schema TO yourusr;
    GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA your_schema TO yourusr;
    GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA your_schema TO yourusr;
```