# Django model reference to a postgres foreign table (clickhouse_fdw)

Tags: django, postgresql, clickhouse, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

I have a Django project. I've connected a clickhouse table with a postgres table using clickhouse_fdw. 
Following clickhouse_fdw instructions, in postgres I did:

```
CREATE EXTENSION clickhousedb_fdw;
CREATE SERVER clickhouse_svr FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER clickhousedb_fdw OPTIONS(host 'host', dbname 'dbname', driver '/var/lib/postgresql/libclickhouseodbc.so');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER SERVER clickhouse_svr;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE clickhouse_table ("date_from" Date, "date_to" Date ... ) server clickhouse_svr options(table_name 'table');
```

This it's working using psql commands, but now I want to access from django (I can access all the others tables without any problems).
I've added a new model for clickhouse table and ignored migrations and managment for it in django.

Then in django shell I've tried:

```py
ClickHouseTable.objects.all()
```

```py
ClickHouseTable.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM clickhouse_table LIMIT 1')[0]
```

```py
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM clickhouse_table LIMIT 1')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

and with every query I get:

```sh
ProgrammingError: permission denied for foreign table clickhouse_table
```

Also from dbshell:

```sql
database => SELECT * FROM clickhouse_table LIMIT 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for foreign table clickhouse_table
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You Django app needs a full access to the DB. Also, Django provides you ORM. You might consider to use it.

Comment: Yes! Thats what I first did. I've also tried using django orm, something like ClickHouseTable.objects.all() ends with the same error.

Comment: I have never used Django with Postgres. But this error comes from Postgres. It seems you didn't grant permissions to your Django app. Try to follow tutorials like this one: https://medium.com/agatha-codes/painless-postgresql-django-d4f03364989

Comment: But I can access to all tables using Django. The issue is with this foreign data wrapper. I also did GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER myserver TO myuser;

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/give-all-the-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-db

Comment: Cool, I am pretty sure that your app for some reason was't granted all permissions...

Answer (score 0):

I've started from scratch and now it's working. No idea what was going on :/