# Give user permission to drop and create specific databases

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This question refers to MySQL and/or MariaDB specifically.

Is it possible to permit certain users to drop/create one (or more) specific databases, but not all databases? By this, I do not mean how to give users all privileges for certain specific databases with a query like:
`` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `example-db`.* TO 'example-user'@'localhost'; ``

I've found some methods on how to do this for [MSSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29340/sql-server-permissions-to-create-restore-delete-only-some-databases) here and a similar post for [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/give-all-the-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-db).

Answer (score 2):

grant privileges separately for a user account in MySQL.

When specifying the database name and table name, separate them with a. (period) and no spaces. This will give the root user fine-grain control over certain data.

Also, replace the PERMISSION_TYPE value with the kind of access you want to grant to your new user account.

Here are the most used commands in MySQL:

CREATE — enable users to create a database or table

SELECT — permit users to retrieve data

INSERT — let users add new entries in tables

UPDATE — allow users to modify existing entries in tables

DELETE — enable users to erase table entries

DROP — let users delete entire database tables

> NOTE: Using the ALL PRIVILEGES permission type from before will allow
> all of the permissions listed above.

To use any of these options, simply replace PERMISSION_TYPE with the appropriate keyword. To apply multiple privileges, separate them with a comma. For example, we can assign CREATE and SELECT to our non-root MySQL user account with this command:

```
GRANT CREATE, SELECT ON * . * TO 'user_name'@'localhost';
```

Sometimes, you might come across a situation where you need to revoke given privileges from a user. You can do so by entering:

```
REVOKE PERMISSION_TYPE ON database_name.table_name FROM ‘user_name’@‘localhost’;
```

For example, to withdraw all privileges for our non-root user we should use:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * FROM 'user_name'@'localhost';
```

Finally, you can entirely delete an existing user account by using the following command:

```
DROP USER ‘user_name’@‘localhost’;
```

Don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

In order to find what privileges have already been granted to a MySQL user, you can use the SHOW GRANTS command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user_name'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score -2):

Let’s start by making a new user within the MySQL shell:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

To provide a specific user with permission, you can use this framework:

```
GRANT type_of_permission ON database_name.table_name TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```