# Why am I unable to connect to my database as my created user, despite having all privileges?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made a post yesterday to fix the issues with my database code, and I had a few typos to fix and it works now. The only problem is I can only connect to my database as the default postgres user, when I want to connect as my created user in the file. I pictured the status below:

```
CREATE DATABASE equipment;
CREATE USER equipment WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'testing';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "equipment" to equipment;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO equipment;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE equipment TO equipment;
ALTER USER equipment WITH SUPERUSER;
\c equipment equipment;


CREATE TABLE material (
          material_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
          name            VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
          description     VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          tensile_strength INTEGER NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY     ( material_id )
);

CREATE TABLE costs (
          cost_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
          material_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          price          DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_material_id FOREIGN KEY (material_id) REFERENCES material(material_id)
          PRIMARY KEY     ( cost_id )
);

CREATE TABLE usages (
          usage_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
          cost_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
          purpose          VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          location_to_purchase  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_cost_id FOREIGN KEY (cost_id) REFERENCES costs(cost_id)
          PRIMARY KEY ( usage_id )

);

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON material, costs, usages TO equipment;
```

EDIT: can connect with equipment user after editing pg_hba.conf;

Content containing changes in the conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             equipment                               md5
```

After running this this is the output:

```
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
ALTER ROLE
Password for user equipment:
```

Entering 'testing' allows me in (Is there an automatic way to enter this?)

Comment: Does you user have access to log in?  Or just denied on the database itself?  My guess is they don't have privileges to access anything from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` -  Can you show us your `CREATE USER` SQL ?

Comment: @Zak The CREATE USER statement is at the top of the file, and if I granted all privileges to the equipment user, shouldn't it be able to login?

Comment: So what is the issue here? You cannot connect as user `equipment` to the database? Because your screenshots  do not show that?

Comment: @Mushroomator Yes that is the issue; I cannot connect to the database as the equipment user. I apologize if I am missing something, I just don't know what that is; I am quite new to this.

Comment: In my code .. database name is in quotes .. Does that help? `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "equipment" to equipment` ?

Comment: Also did you read through [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/postgresql-give-all-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: Yes; it still is only connecting as user postgres. And the double quotes did not fix it either.

Comment: 1) Do not use image for textual information. Copy and paste text to question 2) `USE` is not a Postgres command. 3) `\c  equipment` will connect to `equipment` database as current user `postgres`. If you want to connect as `equipment` user then do `\c equipment equipment`. 4) Read the docs [psql] `\c or \connect [ -reuse-previous=on|off ] [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] | conninfo ]`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I made this change and get   FATAL: peer authentication failed for user "equipment"

Comment: Then you need to modify [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and reload it.

Comment: The problem with doing that is this file is getting submitted to a teacher, and wouldn't he have to make the same config file edit in order to run it?

Comment: Depends is he using the same conf files? In any case connection access to the database is controlled by `pg_hba.conf`. You will need to at least look at it to see if there may be a way to access that does not require a change. If you post the text of the file to your question we maybe able to offer pointers.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is everything I have in the top of it now
CREATE DATABASE equipment;
CREATE USER equipment WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'testing';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "equipment" to equipment;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO equipment;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE equipment TO equipment;
ALTER USER equipment WITH SUPERUSER;
\c equipment equipment;

Comment: 1) Do not put revisions in the comments, update your question with the changes. 2) The important part at this point is the contents of `pg_hba.conf`. That also needs to added **as text** to the question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for your input and assistance. I've updated the question

Comment: 1) Change `md5` to `trust`, that means no password needed. 2) On `\c` use `conninfo` as shown here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and here [connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) . 3) Use [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgpass.html) 4) Use [environment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) variables