# Postgres 15. permission denied for schema public

Tags: sql, postgresql, debian, postgresql-15

Can't create tables in public schema as non-superuser

postgres - super user.

What I've done:

```
ALTER SCHEMA public owner to postgres;  

CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'my-password';   

GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;   
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO admin;    

CREATE DATABASE mydb;    
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO admin;
```

privileges:

```
postgres=# \dn+
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres        +| 
        |          | admin=UC/postgres    | 
(1 row)
```

what I got:

[image]

How to create tables in public schema?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-released-2526/

`PostgreSQL 15 also revokes the CREATE permission from all users except a database owner from the public (or default) schema`

Comment: "postgres" owner database.
"postgres" owner schema "public".
\dn+ shows that the admin has full access to the schema, but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74110708/postgres-15-permission-denied-for-schema-public/74111630#comment130849690_74110708) nailed the most likely reason this is happening. Quoting the [release announcement](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-released-2526/#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%2015%20also%20revokes%20the%20CREATE%20permission%20from%20all%20users%20except%20a%20database%20owner%20from%20the%20public):

> PostgreSQL 15 also **revokes the `CREATE` permission from all users** except a database owner from the `public` (or default) schema.

The reason your fix didn't work is that all actions you took on database `postgres` in regards to user `admin`'s privileges on schema `public` concern only that schema within the database `postgres`. Schema `public` on database `postgres` is not the same schema `public` as the one on newly created `mydb`.

Also, this:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO admin;
```

grants privileges on the database itself, not things within the database. `admin` can now drop the database, for example, still without being able to create tables in schema `public`. My guess is that you wanted to make `admin` also the owner of `mydb`, in which case you need to add

```sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb OWNER TO admin;
```

Or you need to repeat your `GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO admin;` on `mydb`.

Here's some more documentation on [*secure schema usage patterns*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS) the PostgreSQL 15 change was based on.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that public is different. How can i execute the command:
`GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO admin;`
For the public schema on "mydb"? Sorry if my question is stupid)

`ALTER DATABASE mydb OWNER TO admin;`
This work, but not what I was looking for)

Comment: Depending on what db client/IDE you are in, you might need to create a new connection. However you connected to database `postgres` at the moment, you should do the same again and just replace the database name in connection settings to `mydb`. Once you're in, you can make sure by issuing `select current_database(), current_user;`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!

`postgres=# \c myDB`
and
`myDB=# GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO admin;`

Comment: Special thanks, I was stuck for two days on this issue, the `keycloak` was not able to access to the `public schema`.

Comment: You also may need `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLESPACE tsname TO username;`

Answer (score 1):

You have created the DB **after** having granted the privileges on the `public` schema. Chances are your `admin` user is using the new DB, which only have the default priviledges