# postgresql: permission denied for relation

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm building a project using postgresql and java (NetBeans).

When I try to execute a simple query (select * from customer) I get an error, telling me that "permission denied for relation customer".

When I searched for an answer, all I found was about granting user privileges, so I went into pgAdmin and wrote "grant all privileges on database dirty to henrik;" .

That didn't change anything - and that's why I'm making a new post..

The complete error message output of the program:

```
run:
1
2
3

Mar 23, 2014 7:47:18 PM sletdendog.SletDenDog main
SEVERE: ERROR: permission denied for relation customer
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation customer
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at sletdendog.SletDenDog.main(SletDenDog.java:27)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The java program is really simple - it looks like this:

```
package sletdendog;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SletDenDog {

private static Connection connection = null;
private static PreparedStatement statement = null;
private static ResultSet result = null;
private static ResultSetMetaData meta = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try{
        System.out.println("1");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dirty", "henrik", "hokus pokus");
        System.out.println("2");
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from customer;");
        System.out.println("3");
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("4");
        meta = result.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("5");
        for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(meta.getColumnName(i));
        }
                
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(SletDenDog.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        try{
            if(connection != null){
                connection.close();
            }
            if(statement != null){
                statement.close();
            }
            if(result != null){
                result.close();
            }
        } catch(SQLException ex){
     
            System.out.println("Something wasn't closed...");
        
        }
    }   
}   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Privileges on the database are not enough.
You also need at least the `USAGE` privilege for relevant schema and the `SELECT` privilege for the table.

More details in this closely related answer:
[How to grant all privileges on views to arbitrary user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275#10491275)

Comment: That solved it. Kind of misleading that the "grant all privileges" command doesn't grant all privileges though :/
Guess I have to read a whole lot more about users and privileges when I'm done with this project.
But thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Henry: Well, it *does* [grant all privileges for database access: (`CREATE`, `CONNECT`, `TEMP`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html).