# permission denied for relation django_migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-cms

I am using Django CMS, I want to take backup of my database. But when I am firing the query to take my back of database:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 db_name > db_name_backup.sql
```

After firing the query I am getting the following error:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation django_migrations
>
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.django_migrations IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grant all privileges on views to arbitrary user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it's down to permissions, so make sure you at least have `USAGE` for relevant schema and the `SELECT` privilege for the table.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275#10491275) for much greater detail.