# Error in PostgreSQL permission denied fo

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

While trying to access my PostgreSQL database I get an error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> 16:34:13: Error: ERROR:  permission denied for relation account_account_account_tag

What is the problem? How to solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems quite similar to the following question. See whether it helps or not - 
[ERROR: permission denied for relation tablename on Postgres while trying a SELECT as a readonly user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec)

Comment: i will try that command but i cant find any perfect solution.

Comment: i think my error is different from this. because i cant access my Database form GUI too.

Comment: Here is also a selected answer with the same command. Hope it helps. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275#10491275