# upgrade user to superuser in postgres google cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-console

How do I create a user with superuser role in Postgres serwer with google cloud console?

When I create databases in google cloud, the default user is a non-superuser. From this role it is not possible to upgrade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

no way:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users

> The postgres user is part of the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role, and has the
>   following attributes (privileges): CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN. It
>   does not have the `SUPERUSER` or `REPLICATION` attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I read it, but I hoped somehow there was a way to corner it, maybe in powerShell connected to google cloud. :-)

Comment: Really?? No way?

Comment: An opdate to this: I changed from Google Cloud Postgres to a VS and installed Postgres on that one instead. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own script:

```
GRANT cloudsqlimportexport, cloudsqlsuperuser, pg_read_all_data, pg_write_all_data, postgres TO myawsumuser WITH ADMIN OPTION;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mytestdb1 TO myawsumuser WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres TO myawsumuser WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myawsumuser with grant option;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myawsumuser with grant option;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO myawsumuser with admin option;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO myawsumuser with grant option;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO myawsumuser with grant option;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO myawsumuser with grant option;
```

Good links:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users

[How to grant all privileges on views to arbitrary user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491208/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-views-to-arbitrary-user/10491275#10491275)