# What does GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA do exactly?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, sql-grant, database-permissions

I'm trying to create a Postgres database for the first time.

I assigned basic read-only permissions to the DB role that must access the database from my PHP scripts, and I have a curiosity: If I execute

```
GRANT some_or_all_privileges ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema TO role;
```

is there any need to also execute this?

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema TO role;
```

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html):

> USAGE: For schemas, allows access to objects contained in the
> specified schema (assuming that the objects' own privilege
> requirements are also met). Essentially this allows the grantee to
> "look up" objects within the schema.

I think that if I can select or manipulate any data contained in the schema, I can access to any objects of the schema itself. Am I wrong? If not, what is `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA` used for? And what does the documentation mean exactly with "assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also met"?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

`GRANT`s on different objects are separate. `GRANT`ing on a database doesn't `GRANT` rights to the schema within. Similiarly, `GRANT`ing on a schema doesn't grant rights on the tables within.

If you have rights to `SELECT` from a table, but not the right to see it in the schema that contains it then you can't access the table.

The rights tests are done in order:

```
Do you have `USAGE` on the schema? 
    No:  Reject access. 
    Yes: Do you also have the appropriate rights on the table? 
        No:  Reject access. 
        Yes: Check column privileges.
```

Your confusion may arise from the fact that the `public` schema has a default `GRANT` of all rights to the role `public`, which every user/group is a member of. So everyone already has usage on that schema.

The phrase:

> (assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also met)

Is saying that you must have `USAGE` on a schema to use objects within it, but having `USAGE` on a schema is not by itself sufficient to use the objects within the schema, you must also have rights on the objects themselves.

It's like a directory tree. If you create a directory `somedir` with file `somefile` within it then set it so that only your own user can access the directory or the file (mode `rwx------` on the dir, mode `rw-------` on the file) then nobody else can list the directory to see that the file exists.

If you were to grant world-read rights on the file (mode `rw-r--r--`) but not change the directory permissions it'd make no difference. Nobody could *see* the file in order to read it, because they don't have the rights to list the directory.

If you instead set `rwx-r-xr-x` on the directory, setting it so people can list and traverse the directory but not changing the file permissions, people could *list* the file but could not *read* it because they'd have no access to the file.

You need to set *both* permissions for people to actually be able to view the file.

Same thing in Pg. You need both schema `USAGE` rights and object rights to perform an action on an object, like `SELECT` from a table.

(The analogy falls down a bit in that PostgreSQL doesn't have row-level security yet, so the user can still "see" that the table exists in the schema by `SELECT`ing from `pg_class` directly. They can't interact with it in any way, though, so it's just the "list" part that isn't quite the same.)

Comment: Now it's very clear with the directory example :) I must say this is a problem if you insert some table or row with a superuser, for example when you add postGIS using `CREATE EXTENSION`. It's more or less the same problem with files created on Linux while you're `su`. It will be good if there's a sort of `sudo -e` for statements in pqsl.

Comment: Anyway now I realized that `GRANT` statements not specific for tables are not what I want, since they affect all databases... :s

Comment: @LucasMalor Er... no, they don't. `GRANT` on a schema affects that schema. `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...` affects all tables in a schema in a particular database. There are no `GRANT`s that affect all databases (ok, except `GRANT`ing role membership to a user).

Comment: Ah excuse me, I executed the statements when I was logged as "postgres" superuser, and they affected the "postgres" database. I thought that if you run `psql` without `-d db` you're operating "outside" any db, but you're always connected to a db and by default you're connected to the db with the same name of your role. db = role = user = group... it's a bit confusing :D

Comment: @LucasMalor Think of it this way. *By default* you connect to a DB with the same name as the *login role* ("user") you connect as. "Users" are just roles that have `WITH LOGIN`; essentially, everything can be a group, and groups can be set to be able to log in.

Comment: `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGIES` does not work with tables and views created when you install postgis, because "You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of." (http://postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html). I have to assign the correct privileges to the local and remote role. This is what I have done: http://pastebin.com/gshaYdMd PS: thank you for your precious help! :)

Answer (score 133):

For a production system, you can use this configuration :

```
--ACCESS DB
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE nova FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT  CONNECT ON DATABASE nova  TO user;

--ACCESS SCHEMA
REVOKE ALL     ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT  USAGE   ON SCHEMA public  TO user;

--ACCESS TABLES
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC ;
GRANT SELECT                         ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only ;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_write ;
GRANT ALL                            ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO admin ;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `admin` also be granted `CREATE` on the schema?

Comment: The access are allocated according to a hierarchical model : **BD --> SCHEMA --> TABLES** . 
With `GRANT  USAGE ON SCHEMA` , the admin user can't create table but he can do it with `ALL GRANT  ALL ON SCHEMA` ....

Comment: @bilelovitch: you mean `grant all on schema public to admin`? PS: I added also 
`grant usage, select on all sequences in schema public to read_only/read_write;`
`grant execute on all functions in schema public to read_only/read_write;`

Answer (score 10):

Well, this is my final solution for a simple db, for Linux:

```sql
# Read this before!
#
# * roles in postgres are users, and can be used also as group of users
# * $ROLE_LOCAL will be the user that access the db for maintenance and
#   administration. $ROLE_REMOTE will be the user that access the db from the webapp
# * you have to change '$ROLE_LOCAL', '$ROLE_REMOTE' and '$DB'
#   strings with your desired names
# * it's preferable that $ROLE_LOCAL == $DB

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//----------- SKIP THIS PART UNTIL POSTGRES JDBC ADDS SCRAM - START ----------//

cd /etc/postgresql/$VERSION/main
sudo cp pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf_bak
sudo -e pg_hba.conf

# change all `md5` with `scram-sha-256`
# save and exit

//------------ SKIP THIS PART UNTIL POSTGRES JDBC ADDS SCRAM - END -----------//

sudo -u postgres psql

# in psql:
create role $ROLE_LOCAL login createdb;
\password $ROLE_LOCAL
create role $ROLE_REMOTE login;
\password $ROLE_REMOTE

create database $DB owner $ROLE_LOCAL encoding "utf8";
\connect $DB $ROLE_LOCAL

# Create all tables and objects, and after that:

\connect $DB postgres

revoke connect on database $DB from public;
revoke all on schema public from public;
revoke all on all tables in schema public from public;

grant connect on database $DB to $ROLE_LOCAL;
grant all on schema public to $ROLE_LOCAL;
grant all on all tables in schema public to $ROLE_LOCAL;
grant all on all sequences in schema public to $ROLE_LOCAL;
grant all on all functions in schema public to $ROLE_LOCAL;

grant connect on database $DB to $ROLE_REMOTE;
grant usage on schema public to $ROLE_REMOTE;
grant select, insert, update, delete on all tables in schema public to $ROLE_REMOTE;
grant usage, select on all sequences in schema public to $ROLE_REMOTE;
grant execute on all functions in schema public to $ROLE_REMOTE;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_LOCAL in schema public
    grant all on tables to $ROLE_LOCAL;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_LOCAL in schema public
    grant all on sequences to $ROLE_LOCAL;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_LOCAL in schema public
    grant all on functions to $ROLE_LOCAL;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_REMOTE in schema public
    grant select, insert, update, delete on tables to $ROLE_REMOTE;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_REMOTE in schema public
    grant usage, select on sequences to $ROLE_REMOTE;

alter default privileges for role $ROLE_REMOTE in schema public
    grant execute on functions to $ROLE_REMOTE;

# CTRL+D
```

Comment: Which user has to be used for the "# Create all tables and objects, and after that:"? Who is the owner of the tables and other objects in your case?

Comment: @ChristopheFurmaniak you're right, I corrected the process. The owner of the db and its objects is $ROLE_LOCAL and, after creating the db structure, we must return to postgres superuser.

Comment: I believe you have an issue in your "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ..." commands. This command is used to trigger grant privileges to one user (role) when a different user (role) creates an object. See page 11, section 7.1, of this [doc](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/d/d1/Managing_rights_in_postgresql.pdf) for clarification.
Currently your ROLE_REMOTE will not have access to any objects that ROLE_LOCAL would create. The ROLE_LOCAL commands are only giving privs that the role already has as Owner of those objects. Same goes for ROLE_REMOTE commands.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to perform operations with the database only after the user was assigned

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE chat_db to chat_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA security_user TO chat_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA security_user TO chat_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE web_history_migration TO chat_user;
ALTER SCHEMA security_user OWNER TO chat_user;
```

since I used flywaydb there.

although maybe it would be enough :

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA security_user OWNER TO chat_user;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also this is granting everything to the chat_user.