# Grant read-only permissions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to assigned basic read-only permissions for a PostgreSQL database role that must access from an Application server like Glassfish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a production system, you can use the configuration described in this post :
[What GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338621/what-grant-usage-on-schema-exactly-do/28849656#28849656)