# Revoke access from PostgreSQL User to see other tables

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a PostgreSQL DB user "limited_user" and want to give SELECT permission on one table ONLY.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "db1" TO limited_user;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE users to limited_user;
```

What happens is that when I try \dt , the user can see all the other tables in this db1, while he can perform SELECT operation to table "user" as I gave permission. How can I revoke access access to the user so that he can not see other tables and just one table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not in any straightforward way that I am aware of.

Tables exist within the schema namespace, and schemas exist within the database. To give access to a user on a particular table means you must also give that user the `USAGE` permission on the schema to which the table belongs. `USAGE` does not grant permissions on the tables themselves, only the the schema in question. But table *definitions* are part of the schema, so `USAGE` does allow the user to see table names (and the columns too).

But if there are other tables in the same schema, the user will not be able to `SELECT` from those tables unless you also `GRANT SELECT` on those tables, even though they will be able to see that they exist.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355059/6689725) gives a pretty clear explanation of the permission system.

**Edit to add:**
One way to achieve a similar outcome would be like this (using `psql`):

```
sec_schema=# REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sec_schema FROM restricted_user;
REVOKE
sec_schema=# REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA sec_schema FROM restricted_user;
REVOKE
sec_schema=# CREATE SCHEMA new_schema;
CREATE SCHEMA
sec_schema=# GRANT USAGE ON new_schema TO restricted_user;
GRANT
sec_schema=# CREATE VIEW new_schema.secret_view AS SELECT * from sec_schema.secret_table;
CREATE VIEW
sec_schema=# GRANT SELECT ON new_schema.secret_view TO restricted_user;
GRANT
```

This will remove all access to the schema `sec_schema` for user `restricted_user`, but then creates `new_schema` and `new_schema.secret_view` which is a cover view over `sec_schema.secret_table`. After the `GRANT SELECT`, the user will be able to read the data from table `sec_schema.secret_table` through the view, but they will not be able to see any objects in `sec_schema`.