# Add privileges to group role without knowing schema name

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, privileges, ddl

How to add privileges to a role (act as group) without specifying particular schema. Basically I have a database with a schema (`my_first_schema`). I create multiple new schemas by cloning `my_first_schema`. Then create a new database user and GRANT my group privileges to this user.

How to add privileges to group role without knowing schema name (because I create schema dynamically)?

**Update**
  I tried to revoke all privileges on all schemas in database and grant select privilege to a dynamically created schema,so that the user can access the a particular schema only. But it revokes all privileges on all tables in all database and I got Permission denied error message after grant SELECT privilege to particular schema for the user.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM PUBLIC;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA john_smith_gmail_com GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO john_smith_gmail_com;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), but it's only available for tables, sequences, functions and types. **Not** for schemas. More in this related answer:
[Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730)

However, if you create a schema dynamically, you can add privileges to the role dynamically as well. For instance, if you are doing all of this in a plpgsql function, incorporate this (without the `DO` wrapper):

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA %I TO mygroup', new_schema);
END
$$
```

[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) requires Postgres 9.1 or later.
Be sure to [properly escape identifiers for dynamic SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718).