# Alter default privileges for a group role in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.2, privileges

I have created two group roles in Postgres 9.2: one is called `admins` and the other is called `readers`.

The idea is very simple: `admins` create tables and `readers` have read access to these tables.

After granting privileges to both group roles everything worked as expected for exisintg objects. But now what about new objects?

So after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10352695/972208) I altered the default privileges to grant `SELECT` privileges to `readers` for any new table that `admins` create:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE admins IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readers;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE admins IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO readers;
```

But apparently, `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects the role itself but not the members of the role. Let me show you.

If I login as `userX` (a member of `admins`) and create a new table, **no default privileges are granted** (and therefore, `readers` cannot access this table):

```
test=# CREATE TABLE table1 (name VARCHAR(10)); -- Creating table as userX
test=# \dp table1
                           Access privileges
 Schema |  Name  | Type  | Access privileges | Column access privileges 
--------+--------+-------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | table1 | table |                   |
```

However, the **default privileges are granted** if I create the table as `admins` (`readers` can access this table):

```
test=# SET ROLE admins;
test=# CREATE TABLE table2 (name VARCHAR(10)); -- Creating table as admins
test=# \dp table2
                             Access privileges
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |   Access privileges   | Column access privileges 
--------+--------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------------
 public | table2 | table | readers=r/admins     +| 
        |        |       | admins=arwdDxt/admins |
```

Is there a way to alter the default privileges for ALL members of a group role? Or should I just alter default privileges for each user?

---

**UPDATE:** [In this PostgreSQL forum someone asked a very similar question](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/ALTER-DEFAULT-PRIVILEGES-target-role-doesn-t-work-with-group-roles-td5503501.html) and the answer was:

> Unfortunately I can't see a way to achieve what you want without granting default privileges to everybody involved.

However this question was asked 2 years ago. Is there a solution now?

Comment: I was trying to achieve this too but I think this could cause some kind of diamond problem. If a user is member of more than one group role, which default privileges should be granted?

Comment: Trying very similar thing, but involving also SCHEMA and VIEWS, granting SELECT  rights to the_reader , for future created VIEW(s) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238766/postgresql-9-user-cannot-select-from-view-inside-a-schema-as-default-privile  . In mine, I just use users (not groups) and I use a schema as "userspace", where a manager can write any view.

Answer (score 21):

If a user creates a table then this user becomes the owner of the table. So in your case any default privileges for userX apply, not those of admins. the solution is to `SET ROLE admins` before creating your table:

```
SET ROLE admins;
CREATE TABLE ... -- This now applies default privileges of admins
;
RESET ROLE;
```

More in general, you would want to do this always: Create all tables and views through a group role or some other role not used in daily operations and grant access to the relations to another group role whose privileges are inherited by regular login roles (users). This greatly facilitates security management.

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Very helpful! Just to piggy back on this - the sticking point for me was this line: "You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of." So really, `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` really means `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES --(on objects created by the current user)`