# Postgresql permissions keep failing

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.3, database-permissions

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on Linux.

I have a group role 'data_scientist' and permissions to a particular (already populated) schema like so

```
grant usage on schema schemaname to data_scientist;

grant select, references, trigger
    on all tables in schema schemaname
    to data_scientist;
```

This fixes the problem of data_scientist using past tables. For future tables I added

```
alter default privileges in schema schemaname
grant select, references on tables
   to data_scientist;
```

Still, whenever a new table is added, other data_scientist's permissions fail on the new tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql seems to answer this by specifying DEFAULT PRIVILEGES to specify access to new objects created in a schema

Comment: In fact that is the second part I add. Still, it does not work.

Comment: @mc110 it is important to keep FOR in mind as well since default privileges are per user/role and it default to a current user who issues the statement.

Comment: @mlt I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the FOR, could you exemplify?

Comment: If you do **not** have a role *data_scientist* when connected to DB while issuing *alter* statements, then you **must** use *for data_scientist* role, otherwise default privileges would be applied for new tables created only by your user you used to issue *alter* statement. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513996/alter-default-privileges-for-a-group-role-in-postgresql) also might be relevant. That is make sure `set role` was used if *data_scientist* as a group role before creating a table. I believe that this Q is a duplicate of the one I linked.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES only applies to the role that ran the command.  Suppose we have 2 users: ramfjord and animalito.  If I (ramfjord) run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO public; CREATE TABLE ramfjord_table;
```

Then animalito will be able to see it.  If animalito runs

```
CREATE TABLE animalito_table
```

Then ramfjord won't be able to see it, because ramfjord's default privileges don't apply.  See default privileges and their owners with `\ddp`

Because of this, we've stopped using default privileges at my company, and started using explicit GRANT's.  To remove default privs, you have to run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <owner> REVOKE...
```

The owner, schema, relation type and privileges have to match those listed in `\ddp` for this command to do anything.  **Do not** just delete everything from the internal table that stores default privileges... trust me.