# Grant privileges on all future tables, independently of their owner

Tags: postgresql, privileges, sql-grant

I read the following question before: [Grant privileges on future tables in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684255/grant-privileges-on-future-tables-in-postgresql).

But if I run the following query while logged in as `rbourgeon` (which is a superuser):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ALL ON TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO username;
```

I notice that the user `username` will have the privileges only on the future tables **created by me**, and not on all the future tables.

The [official PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), on this issue, reads:

> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be
>   applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect
>   privileges assigned to already-existing objects.) Currently, only the
>   privileges for tables (including views), sequences, and functions can
>   be altered.
>
> **You can change default privileges only for objects that will be
>   created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.** The
>   privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the
>   current database), or just for objects created in specified schemas.
>   Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever
>   the global default privileges are for the particular object type.

Is there a workaround? Because many users may create tables in this database.

Comment: well, this can be seen as a problem from practical point of view of small company because it mean to include granting into tasks but from security point of view of a really big company it makes sense because other users could be surprised that their objects are visible to others - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513996/alter-default-privileges-for-a-group-role-in-postgresql

Comment: You will need to use the `target_role` (`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR xyz …`) to change the default privileges for all users that may create tables.