# Change all of the table owners within a schema

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I'm currently using the following postgres query and then copying the data output and running to change all of the tables in a specified schema. What's the best way so that I don't have to always run, such as a stored procedure?

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' OWNER TO new_owner;' 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'specified_schema';
```

Comment: Do you actually need to change the owner, or is it enough to GRANT certain privileges to `new_owner`? In the latter case, continue reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730) and [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53914/pg-permission-denied-for-relation-table/53936#53936).

Comment: I actually need to change the owner.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure must be run as well, you gain nothing.

I would create a cron job and put it in cron/{hourly,daily} - provided that it is the best alternative to solve the problem.

You do not give any information to judge that.