# Create PostgreSQL read only user ERROR: permission denied for relation _foo

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges, ckan

I have an issue while trying to create a readonly user in PostgreSQL.

I want user ckan_default to create tables in database datastore_default.
And I want readonlyuser to read tables created by ckan_default in datastore_default.
I want this rule to apply to tables that will be created by ckan_default, not only the ones already created.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE datastore_default TO readonlyuser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER readonlyuser IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonlyuser;
```

acutally the complete script I ran was

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres -f /tmp/set_permissions.sql

--content of /tmp/set_permissions.sql
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO ckan_default;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ckan_default;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO ckan_default;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ckan_default;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE ckan_default FROM readonlyuser;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE datastore_default TO readonlyuser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonlyuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER ckan_default IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonlyuser;
```

I read this post [How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql) and I either tried it or it does not work for tables that will be created.

For more details and the complete script check out the pastebin http://pastebin.com/psDifhwd

Comment: I studied your pastebin link, actual granting of privileges happens in another pastebin referenced in a comment in the first: http://pastebin.com/FDnt6EhS. The content of this file should be ***in*** your question. Links die and then your question stops making sense. Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the `search_path` of all users is set to the typical default

```
"$user",public
```

Which means `_foo` without schema-qualification would resolve to `$user._foo`:

- `ckan_default._foo` for `ckan_default`, and
- `readonlyuser._foo` for `readonlyuser`.

Repeat your test with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U ckan_default -c 'CREATE TABLE public._foo()'
sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U ckan_default -c 'SELECT * FROM public._foo'
sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U readonlyuser -c 'SELECT * FROM public._foo'
```

If that's the case, consider changing the default `search_path` for each user:

```
ALTER ROLE ckan_default SET search_path=public;
ALTER ROLE readonlyuser SET search_path=public;
```

Or whatever suits your needs.
Also consider changing the default setting in `postgresql.conf`.

More related answers:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)
- [Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730)
- [Grant privileges for a particular database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918367/grant-privileges-for-a-particular-database-in-postgresql/24923877#24923877)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it appears that it is not a search_path issue. ckan_default sees public._foo but readonlyuser does not.  

`$ sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U readonlyuser -c 'SELECT * FROM public._foo'
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public._foo
                      ^`

Comment: if I run \z with users postgres or ckan_default I get this

    `sudo -u postgres psql -d datastore_default -U`
    `ckan_default=arwdDxt/ckan_default+| 
    datastore_default=r/ckan_default +| 
    readonlyuser=r/ckan_default       | 
    ckan_default=arwdDxt/ckan_default+| 
    datastore_default=r/ckan_default +| 
    readonlyuser=r/ckan_default       | `

But readonlyuser gets an empty row.
sudo -u postgres psql -d readonlyuser -U
More details here http://pastebin.com/CVdHURPJ Any clue?

Comment: `sudo -u postgres dropuser readonlyuser`
It appears that there are some privileges linked to readonlyuser anyway 
`dropuser: removal of role "readonlyuser" failed: ERROR:  role "readonlyuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role postgres in schema public
privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role ckan_default in schema public
privileges for schema public
privileges for database datastore_default
4 objects in database datastore_default`