# Dump or restore Postgresql databases without Postgis functions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis, postgresql-8.4

I want to dump 4 databases from postgresql 8.4 to migrate to Postgresql 9.1.

I use PostGis on the old Postgresql 8.4 with PgRouting so each database has around 1000 functions. Each time I export all databases, all functions are written in the dump. When I restore the backup file, I get some conflicts when I create an extension of postgis or pgrouting on Postgresql 9.1

Is there anyway to dump databases on 8.4 (create dbs, create schemas, create tables and data) without exporting fucntions as well? Or is there anyway to restore the databases on 9.1 without creating the functions on the backup file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627095/exclude-function-definitions-when-dumping-a-postgresql-database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Databases with PostGIS need to follow a specific update procedure. You will need to follow a "hard upgrade" procedure [documented here](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade).

On your 8.4 database:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f "/somepath/olddb.backup" olddb
```

And on the 9.1 database, maybe start with these (if you haven't already done so):

```
createdb [yourdatabase]
psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

Then restore the data using a special `postgis_restore.pl` script:

```
perl utils/postgis_restore.pl "/somepath/olddb.backup" | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres newdb 2> errors.txt
```

Comment: Where can one find the `postgis_restore.pl` script? I think I found it here, but it would be nice to see it coming from a more official source: https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/wheezy/main/i386/postgresql-9.1-postgis/1.5.3-2/file/usr/share/postgresql-9.1-postgis/utils/postgis_restore.pl

Comment: Ah, it looks like I found it here: https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-2.1/utils/postgis_restore.pl.in But it looks like that some variables would have to be injected before making that script executable

Comment: @Lucas the correct script is usually packaged and installed on your system. While you could download an external script, you'd need to be careful in getting the correct version.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it would be useful to document where that script is located on the machine. Also some information about how to run that script when using a tool like RDS or Docker would be helpful.

Comment: @Lucas it depends on how PostgreSQL was configured/packaged/installed. For instance, with the apt-browse link you provided above, it is in `/usr/share/postgresql-9.1-postgis/utils`, and on a Windows computer I see this in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\utils`. You'll need to investigate where this is yourself.